# MYSQL different columns for corresponding person values in one row with different titles

Tags: mysql

I am having 7 tables to get the data.Below listed tables

```
SELECT

        visits.policy_id,persons.full_name,visits.person_id,visits.date,
        (CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Blood Glucose (Fasting)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS BSL_F,  
        (CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Blood Glucose (Post Prandial ) 2 hrs' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS BSL_PP, 
        (CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Triglycerides (Fasting)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS TGL,
        (CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Low Density Lipoprotein (LDL)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS LDL, 
        (CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'HDL (Fasting)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS HDL,
        (CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Total Cholesterol (Fasting)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS Total_Cholesterol
FROM 
visits,provider_locations,providers,visit_test_entries,test_types,persons,households hh

WHERE 
        visits.provider_location_id=provider_locations.id 
        AND visits.provider_id=providers.id
        AND visits.id=visit_test_entries.visit_id
        AND visit_test_entries.test_type_id=test_types.id
        AND visits.person_id=persons.id
        AND persons.household_id=hh.id
        AND visits.date >="2016-06-01"
        AND visits.provider_location_id=1 
        AND visits.valid_state='valid'
```

1. visits
2. provider location
3. providers
4. visit_test_entries
5. test_types
6. persons
7. households

Now I got output like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
policy_id| full_name|person_id|date      |BSL_F|BSL_PP|TGL|LDL|HDL|Tot_Cho|
---------|----------|---------|----------|-----|------|---|---|---|-------|
AN00234  | Rajesh   | 2309330 |2017-04-02|123  |      |   |   |   |       |
---------|----------|---------|----------|-----|------|---|---|---|-------|
AN00234  | Rajesh   | 2309330 |2017-04-02|     |435   |   |   |   |       |
---------|----------|---------|----------|-----|------|---|---|---|-------|
AN00234  | Rajesh   | 2309330 |2017-04-02|     |      |45 |   |   |       |
---------|----------|---------|----------|-----|------|---|---|---|-------|
AN00234  | Rajesh   | 2309330 |2017-04-02|     |      |   |78 |   |       |
---------|----------|---------|----------|-----|------|---|---|---|-------|
AN00234  | Rajesh   | 2309330 |2017-04-02|     |      |   |   |120|       |
---------|----------|---------|----------|-----|------|---|---|---|-------|
AN00234  | Rajesh   | 2309330 |2017-04-02|     |      |   |   |   |170    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

But I need the output like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
policy_id| full_name|person_id|date      |BSL_F|BSL_PP|TGL|LDL|HDL|Tot_Cho|
---------|----------|---------|----------|-----|------|-------|---|-------|
AN00234  | Rajesh   | 2309330 |2017-04-02|123  | 435  |45 |78 |120|170    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: put max() around each case statement and group by policy_ID, full_name, Person_Id and date.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each case in a max statement and group by the other fields not in aggregate.

Not a fan of the old style ancsii joins but...

This works because we know max(or min) will return the same value because of the group by.

```
SELECT visits.policy_id
     , persons.full_name
     , visits.person_id
     , visits.date
     , max(CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Blood Glucose (Fasting)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS BSL_F
     , max(CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Blood Glucose (Post Prandial ) 2 hrs' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS BSL_PP
     , max(CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Triglycerides (Fasting)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS TGL
     , max(CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Low Density Lipoprotein (LDL)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS LDL
     , max(CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'HDL (Fasting)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS HDL
     , max(CASE WHEN test_types.name = 'Total Cholesterol (Fasting)' THEN visit_test_entries.result ELSE " " END)  AS Total_Cholesterol
FROM visits
   , provider_locations
   , providers
   , visit_test_entries
   , test_types
   , persons
   , households hh
WHERE visits.provider_location_id=provider_locations.id 
  AND visits.provider_id=providers.id
  AND visits.id=visit_test_entries.visit_id
  AND visit_test_entries.test_type_id=test_types.id
  AND visits.person_id=persons.id
  AND persons.household_id=hh.id
  AND visits.date >="2016-06-01"
  AND visits.provider_location_id=1 
  AND visits.valid_state='valid'
GROUP BY visits.policy_id
       , persons.full_name
       , visits.person_id
       , visits.date
```

also not a fan of using " " as the place holder, I'd rather not have an else at all so the value would be `<null>`.

Comment: It works fine, if all the column have the values without NULL.But if any one column having null values then it gives duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but the easiest way for you is a subselect

```
SELECT
   visits.policy_id,persons.full_name,visits.person_id,visits.date,
   ( SELECT
         test_types.result
     FROM
         test_types
     WHERE 1
         AND visit_test_entries.test_type_id = test_types.id
         AND test_types.name = 'Low Density Lipoprotein (LDL)'
   ) AS LDL
   //... and so on
```